# Subtracting hours from time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to subtract hours from a time, but it's giving me strange results

```
A1 = 06:00:00 (manual entry, hours to deduct)
B1 = 00:30:00 (=C1-A1, start time)
C1 = 06:30:00 (manual entry, end time)
```

This works fine and continues to work as long as the difference is 6 hours or less.

Why do I get hashes in B1 if A1 is `07:00:00` for example, or if C1 is `05:00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you **can't** extract more hours then you put in.
In your second example you are trying to subtract 7 hours (A1) from 6 (C1).
In your third example you are trying to subtract 6 hours (A1) from 5 (C1).

If you mean that `A1` is your start-time **of the day** and `C1` is your end-time **of the day**
(where the end-time could be the **next day**) you should use the formula `=C1-A1+IF(C1<A1,1)`.
That way there is a day added to your end-time if the end-time is lower than your begin-time.

Also make the format of your cells `[H]:MM` so the hours are displayed correctly.