# Subtracting hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time, time

I'm working on a time tracking sheet.  I have a weekly total column with the formula of `=SUM(I4:I8)`.  This entire column is formatted as `[h]:mm`.  The current value is `31:49`.  I want to calculate how many hours until 40 (40 - 31:49).  Here are a couple of the things I have tried:

`=TIME(40,0,0)-Table1[@Total]`

`=40-INT(Table1[@Total])`

`=40-Table1[@Total]`

I finally got this to work with a static value: `=TIME(40,0,0)-TIMEVALUE("31:49")`, so then I tried these:

`=TIME(40,0,0)-TIMEVALUE(""&Table1[@Total]&"")`

`=TIME(40,0,0)-TIMEVALUE(INDIRECT(Table1[@Total]))`

I'm sure I'm missing something stupidly obvious, so what is it?

The expected answer is `8:11`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting hours from time](http://superuser.com/questions/689026/subtracting-hours-from-time)

Comment: No, not really the same.

Comment: Are you sure that the Value in the cell is a time and not text that looks like a time?

Comment: Yes, as stated, the format is `[h]:mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below formula.

```
=(40/24)-Table1[@Total]
```

Since in Excel 40 would equal 40 days, you divide by 24 and then subtract your total time to get your time remaining.

Comment: BINGO! I knew it was something silly I was missing.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is pretty close

Try this: `=(TIME(40,0,0)-TIMEVALUE("31:49"))*24`

I formatted the cell as `Number` and I could get the actual hours. Let me know in the comments if you are expecting something else

My result is something like this:
[image]

Comment: First off, that's static.  Second, it results in `196:24` for me...

Comment: The expected answer is `8:11`

Comment: I do not understand when you say `static`

Comment: I mean you put the literal string "31:49" instead of the cell reference.

Comment: Its just an example.

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate, I've updated the answer with a picture of what I have. Let me see how a cell can be referenced in the above formula